# Vlc Radio Launcher

Tags: linux, shell, vlc, linux-mint, internet-radio

I like to listen to one particular radio and I have made myself a little launcher using vlc that is simply like this :

```
#!/bin/sh
vlc http://mp3lg.tdf-cdn.com/fip/all/fiphautdebit.mp3
```

What I would like to do is to have this instance of vlc - I have allowed multiple instances in vlc preferences, immediatly hidden from my desktop. I would like it to run in the 'background'.

How could I achieve this ? I tried to add `>/dev/null` at the end but without success.

I am on Mint 17 Rebecca, and I am trying this both for fun and because RadioTray and GreatLittleRadioPlayer don't work on my system and I haven't been able to find someone with the same issue on the web.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default VLC depends on X, therefore cannot be run headless. You will need to install vlc-nox to run a headless vlc in the background.

Source: [What is vlc-nox?](https://askubuntu.com/q/429693/44293)

Comment: the vlc-nox package contains a command called "cvlc" that is what you want